# Wordpress get the parameter of the first shortcode in the content

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-match

I am writing a script to find the first occurrence of the following shortcode in content and then get the url parameter of the shortcode.

the shortcode looks like this

```
[soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/106046968"]
```

and what i have currently done is

```
$pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
  $matches = array();
  preg_match("/$pattern/s", get_the_content(), $matches);
  print_r($matches);
```

and the result looks like

```
Array (
    [0] => [soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/106046968"]
    [1] =>
    [2] => soundcloud
    [3] => url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/106046968"
    [4] =>
    [5] =>
    [6] =>
)
```

Here is the string from which i need the url of the parameter of the shortcode

```
$html = 'Our good homies <a href="https://www.facebook.com/yungskeeter">DJ Skeet Skeet aka Yung Skeeter</a> &amp; <a href="https://www.facebook.com/WaxMotif">Wax Motif</a> have teamed up to do a colossal 2-track EP and we\'re getting the exclusive sneak-premiere of the EP\'s diabolical techno b-side called "Hush Hush" before its released tomorrow on <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dimmakrecs">Dim Mak Records</a>!

[soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/104477594"]
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/WaxMotif">Wax Motif</a> have teamed up to do a colossal 2-track EP and we\'re getting the exclusive sneak-premiere of the EP\'s diabolical techno b-side called "Hush Hush" before its released tomorrow on <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dimmakrecs">Dim Mak Records</a>!
';
```

I guess this is not the best way to do it. If can guide me how we can do this then it would be great. Basically  i want to extract the first occurrence of soundcloud url from the content.

Comment: You forgot to provide the most essential things: 1- the pattern you're using 2- some input

Comment: the pattern i got using wordpress function. Its ok if i use a custom pattern and regarding the content i will update now

Comment: I've no idea what the pattern is even if it's from a wordpress function. I also don't want to setup WP to just get the pattern. So why don't you just echo the pattern and provide us the core of the problem/code and remove the superfluous information around it.

Comment: The pattern looks like this

`\[(\[?)(embed|wp_caption|caption|gallery|audio|video|fbcomments|mailchimpsf_widget|mailchimpsf_form|soundcloud)(?![\w-])([^\]\/]*(?:\/(?!\])[^\]\/]*)*?)(?:(\/)\]|\](?:([^\[]*+(?:\[(?!\/\2\])[^\[]*+)*+)\[\/\2\])?)(\]?)`

But i don't think we need this much of code.

Comment: ok it seems you were right ... We don't need that much code ...

Comment: Is it possible that there are other parameters than `url` ?

Comment: No only url would be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's what I came up with:

```
preg_match('~\[soundcloud\s+url\s*=\s*("|\')(?<url>.*?)\1\s*\]~i', $input, $m); // match

print_r($m); // print matches (groups) ...
$url = isset($m['url']) ? $m['url']:''; // if the url doesn't exist then return empty string
echo 'The url is : ' . $url; // Just some output
```

Let's explain the regex:

```
~                   # set ~ as delimiter
\[soundcloud        # match [soundcloud
\s+                 # match a whitespace 1 or more times
url                 # match url
\s*                 # match a whitespace 0 or more times
=                   # match =
\s*                 # match a whitespace 0 or more times
("|\')              # match either a double quote or a single quote and put it in group 1
(?<url>.*?)         # match everything ungreedy until group 1 is found and put it in a named group "url"
\1                  # match what was matched in group 1
\s*                 # match a whitespace 0 or more times
\]                  # match ]
~                   # delimiter (end expression)
i                   # set the i modifier, which means match case-insensitive
```

<kbd>[**Online PHP demo**](https://eval.in/45357)</kbd>
               
<kbd>[**Online regex demo**](http://regex101.com/r/jK5kL3)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm. Can't we have something in html dom ? I guess preg_match will be slower right ?

Comment: @NirmalRam In most cases an HTML parser is slower than a wild regex. But it's more reliable. Whether it's possible, I don't know since `[]` is basically not HTML but something like BB code.